# Configure a TextFormField for date-format

Tags: c#, itext7

I put a empty TextFormField on a PDF. I want, that only a specific date format ("DD.MM.YY") can be filled in.

I was looking for examples in the communitiy, but didn't find anything.

```
C#
PdfTextFormField date1 = PdfTextFormField.CreateText(destPdf, new 
Rectangle(200, 200, 60, 8), "_Date", "DD.MM.YY", fontHelvetica, 6);

form.AddField(date1);
```

The goal is, that the field does not allow other formats (best would be, if also 34.10.2019 would be denied)

Comment: Seems like it's better to let the user input their preferred format, as long as it's unambiguous, and then merely store it in your standard format. But that may not be possible in the confines of a PDF.

Comment: I think you should tag this with `itext7` if that is the PDF library you are using.

Comment: That can only be implemented by using JavaScript, and not every PDF browser supports JavaScript.